# Flutter with two windows

Tags: windows, flutter

I am trying to create a gallery app with Flutter on Windows OS. I need to have a second window rather than the main window to be opened as a slideshow for the gallery photos. So the question how can I spawn a second window from my main application window from button pressing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check this discussion / thread on Flutter Repo

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30701

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have submitted this here because I knew of this thread and there is no official solution for it yet. I was looking for third-party solutions if possible.